# ORA-00904 left join on alias

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following snipped code :-

```
SELECT
    q.quoteid,
    cc.Stage_1_Calc
FROM tblquotesnew q
LEFT JOIN VIEW_COMMCALCCHECK cc
    ON q.quoteid = cc.quote_ID
```

Prior to adding the reference to VIEW_COMMCALCCHECK, the query ran fine. Now that reference is there, I get error :-

```
ORA-00904: "CC"."STAGE_1_CALC": invalid identifier
```

I'm guessing this is because `Stage_1_Calc` is an alias?

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: I have provided a a minimal sample.

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: Is `Stage_1_Calc` a column or alias defined in the very top level of the view's `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Yes - SELECT quote_id, 
       Max(CASE 
             WHEN To_number(stage) = 1 THEN 'Yes' 
             ELSE 'No' 
           END) AS "Stage_1_Calc",

Comment: Then I don't know what is the cause of your problem.  At least the question is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AS "Stage_1_Calc"` - you are using doble quotes around the colum name, so this name is treated as [a quoted identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm)

> - A quoted identifier begins and ends with double quotation marks (").    If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, then
>     **you must    use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object.**
> - A nonquoted identifier is not surrounded by any punctuation.

In other worrds, you must use `cc."Stage_1_Calc"` instead of  `cc.Stage_1_Calc` in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT
    q.quoteid,
    cc."Stage_1_Calc"
FROM tblquot .......
......
```

Comment: or remove quote in the alias of the view's column